# htaccess using parameter as folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following problem:
I wrote this on the .htaccess file that is located on `http://somesite.com/b2b/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
# RewriteBase /b2b/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^group/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) groups.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This code should help me on this case of url:

`http://somesite.com/b2b/groups.php?id=1`

And everyone should be able to access this site like this:

`http://somesite.com/b2b/group/1`

Now the problem is that all the CSS and JS files was propperly linked to the `groups.php` file but when I enter the new link `http://somesite.com/b2b/group/1` its throwing me +21 not found errors.
The console log looks like this:

Filed to load resources: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found) http://somesite.com/b2b/group/js/jquery.min.js

It turns out that the server thinks all my JS and CSS files are located in a folder (that not exists) of: group, because of htaccess! Is there any rule to tell HTACCESS to use group only as access keyword but not to navigate as a real folder?

Comment: In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, yeah it worked! Thank you for your answer, there is just one more question! Is there any way to specify it on .htaccess?

Comment: I believe Amit has shared a nice link related to this, kindly go through it if you get related information in it else it could be discussed more, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, saw it just now :) Thank you.